# Script fails to execute in ADO.NET while is OK while running it manually

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, ado.net, npgsql

## Context

Npgsql version 3.2.5

I am trying to write sql generator for ADO.NET/npgsql. The only features of interest are single/bulk insert of related entities with possibility to get back auto-generated values for any of inserts.

## Example

### Context

Scheme

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
(
    id bigserial not null PRIMARY KEY,
    data integer not null
);
```

### Script for manual run in pgAdmin

```
start transaction isolation level READ COMMITTED;

with t as (
    insert into tbl ( data) values ( '1' )
    returning id, data
) select id, data into temporary firstInsert from t;

with t as (
    insert into tbl ( data )
    select data + '1' as data from firstInsert
    returning id
) select id into temporary secondInsert from t;

select id from secondInsert;

-- commit;
```

### C# go

```
string tableName = "tbl";
string columnName = "data";
string autogenColumnName = "id";
string script = $@"
with t as (
    insert into {tableName} ( {columnName} ) values ( '1' )
    returning {autogenColumnName}, {columnName}
) select {autogenColumnName}, {columnName} into temporary firstInsert from t;

with t as (
    insert into {tableName} ( {columnName} )
    select {columnName} + '1' as {columnName} from firstInsert
    returning {autogenColumnName}
) select {autogenColumnName} into temporary secondInsert from t;

select {autogenColumnName} from secondInsert;";

using ( NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection( Executor.Executor.ConnectionString ) )
{
    conn.Open();
    using ( NpgsqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction( System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted ) )
    using ( NpgsqlCommand comm = new NpgsqlCommand( script, conn, transaction ) )
    using ( NpgsqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader() )
    {
        reader.Read();
        reader.GetInt64( 0 );
        reader.Read();
        reader.Close();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

### Problem

Everything is OK with run on pgAdmin, but `Npgsql.PostgresException : 42P01: relation "firstinsert" does not exist` occurs on `.ExecuteReader()` call in c#.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the script actually contains what you want? (I don't use postsgrsql so am not familiar with its syntax requirements but that is the first thing I would check with other DBMS).

Comment: @SoronelHaetir the `script` variable is containing the very same script as one being executed manually in transaction.